# Check for duplicates in list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, duplicates

I want to check if some strings in a column, with random size are duplicated. If it is, python should print out which line the error is observed.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([["s154090","Lis",1,0],["s151515","Lars",2,3],["s151515","Preben",1,0],["s154080","Rene",5,7]])

def sortGrades(data):

    studentId = data[:,0]
    xs = studentId
    s = set()
    if any(i in s or s.add(i) for i in xs):
        s = set()
        duplicates = set(i for i in xs if i in s or s.add(i))
        print("Error in line {},".format(i),"Det følgende Studie ID går igen",duplicates)
    else:
        print("Ingen Fejl")
        return ""
```

But it doesn't work, since `i` isn't defined.

> ---> 11         print("Error in line {},".format(i),"Det følgende Studie ID går igen",duplicates)
>
> NameError: name 'i' is not defined

I am using python 3.5.

Comment: Why did you think a screenshot of your code would be useful? Code is text, please provide it as such - [mcve].

Comment: I didn't have the code available, I only had the screenshot available. I edited my question now, so the code is included :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the exception your approach is a bit too complicated. For example you only need one pass over the data:

```
def sortGrades(data):
    studentId = data[:,0]
    xs = studentId
    s = set()
    for line, val in enumerate(xs):
        if val in s:  # if the current value was already seen print the error message
            print("Error in line {},".format(line),"Det følgende Studie ID går igen", val)
        # Add the value
        s.add(val)

>>> sortGrades(data)
Error in line 2, Det følgende Studie ID går igen s151515
```

Your exception occurs when you try to access loop variables of comprehension outside their scope (which is impossible, at least in python-3.x). So as soon as your comprehension finished you can't access the `i` anymore.

That's why I used an explicit `for`-loop. That way you can access the loop variables.

---

If you want to be really lazy you could also use a function from an external module that I authored: [`iteration_utilities.duplicates`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/duplicates.html)

```
from iteration_utilities import duplicates
from operator import itemgetter

for line, val in duplicates(enumerate(data[:,0]), key=itemgetter(1)):
    print("Error in line {},".format(line),"Det følgende Studie ID går igen", val)
```